# I can't seem to change the location interval using location manager

Tags: java, android

I wanted to update my location every time in selected duration (which is in minutes) which I'm currently having issue with. I tried updating using location manager but it doesn't seem to get updated. I've succeeded in passing the value into the `(int= minutes)` but when I tried to pass it into the `lManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, minutes*60000, 0,this);`
. It just can't update the time interval.

```
public class MyService extends Service implements LocationListener {

private static final String TAG = "MyService";
private LocationManager lManager;
private double lat, lon;
public static final String NOTIFICATION = "NOTIFICATION_FROM_SERVER";
String time;
int minutes;



@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (lManager!=null)
    {
        lManager.removeUpdates(this);
        sendBroadcast("Tracker Stopped");
    }
}

public MyService() {
}

@Override

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    lManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    time = intent.getStringExtra("time");
    minutes = Integer.parseInt(time);
    Log.d(TAG, "minTime: " +minutes);
    lManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, minutes*60000, 0,this);
    if (lManager!=null){
        Location currentLocation = lManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (currentLocation!=null){
            lat = currentLocation.getLatitude();
            lon = currentLocation.getLongitude();
        }
        sendBroadcast("Tracking Device");
    }
    lManager.removeUpdates(this);
    lManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, minutes*60000, 0, this);
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("");
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    lat = location.getLatitude();
    lon = location.getLongitude();
    Log.d(TAG, "Lat: " + lat + " Lon: " + lon);
    CalculateFromServer loc = new CalculateFromServer(lat, lon, minutes);
    loc.execute();
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) { }

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) { }

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) { }

public void sendBroadcast(String location){
    Intent intent = new Intent(NOTIFICATION);
    intent.putExtra("location", location);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}

class CalculateFromServer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    private HashMap<String, Double> parameters;
    private int min;

    public CalculateFromServer(double lat, double lon, int mins) {
        parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("latitude1", lat);
        parameters.put("longitude1", lon);
        min = mins;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        StringBuilder postParameters = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        try{
            URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.143/Task5.2/location.php");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            for(Map.Entry<String, Double> postParams : parameters.entrySet()){
                if (first)
                    first = false;
                else
                    postParameters.append("&");

                postParameters.append(URLEncoder.encode(postParams.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
                postParameters.append("=");
                postParameters.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(postParams.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
            }
            postParameters.append("&selectedUnit=");
            postParameters.append(min);


            OutputStreamWriter oStream = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            oStream.write(postParameters.toString());
            oStream.flush();
            oStream.close();

            BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null){
                result.append(line);
            }
            Log.d("tag", postParameters.toString());
            Log.d("tag100", result.toString());
            return result.toString();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        sendBroadcast(" Longitude: "+lon +"Latitude: " + lat );
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: What's the point of calling `requestLocationUpdates`, then `removeUpdates`, and then `requestLocationUpdates` again?

Comment: it was a just a testing, but apparently nothing happened too